# Looking for live audio webcast engineering help. How should I go about this development?

Tags: flash, audio-streaming, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, low-latency

I have recently started a broadcasting company with my brother. Our company deals strictly with live audio webcasting. Our model allows a single broadcaster to broadcast a one-way audio webcast to multi-point listening devices simultaneously (essentially an online radio webcast).

Our main goal is to use a development model that leaves us with LITTLE TO NO audio latency whatsoever and allows webcasts to work on ALL BROWSERS AND ALL DEVICES.  I am having trouble finding the best way to go about this development. We are thinking of using adobe flash player to allow broadcast to be sent to Wowza streaming engine on AWS. From there it would be transcoded acording to the type of device that is receiving the broadcast (for example, HLS for iOS devices). However, we've been told by other experts in the field that 1. Flash Player is outdated and doesn't work with all devices and 2. HLS transcoding protocols may give us much latency issues with apple products.

Are they right about Flash? What dev path is best to eliminate all audio latency? Would a plug-in to a native app be best to eliminate audio latency? If so, is there a good plug-in api available for our concept? How do you get around HLS transcoding to eliminate latency in apple products?

Also, do you know any engineers or companies that could assist us with the development of these frameworks?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

> Our main goal is to use a development model that leaves us with LITTLE TO NO audio latency

Are you **sure** this is critical to your product's success?  There are important tradeoffs you make to reduce latency.  First, consider the origins of significant latency from source to listener:

- Audio Capture Buffer (50-250ms)
- Codec Buffer - Encoding Side (varies greatly depending on codec and config... 5-2,000ms)
- Network Transmit Buffer (0-500ms depending on bitrate, and whether or not you've disabled the Nagle algorithm)
- Normal Internet Propagation Latency (20ms-300ms for decent connections around the world, varies widely)
- Server-Side Buffer (varies greatly depending on server, protocol, and configuration, but can be anywhere from 100ms to 30s or so)
- Internet Propagation from Edge to Client (if your edge servers are close to your clients, 5ms-80ms is typical for decent connections)
- Client Network Buffer (typically very small, almost nil)
- Client Codec Buffer - Decoding Side (like the encoding side, varies depending on codec and config, but is typically smaller than encoding... 5-400ms -- Can be high though... Android is ~3s, and the same with many desktop players)
- Client Sound Device Buffer (50-250ms)

As you can see, this adds up **very fast**.  To highlight the tradeoffs you can make, consider a couple scenarios:

#### Typical Internet Radio

For a typical internet radio station, the latency from encoding to listening is almost meaningless.  The listeners usually don't interact with the host in any immediate sense, and don't know or care that something live is happening right now or happened 10 seconds ago, or even an hour ago.  For this scenario, I ensure the audio capture buffer on the source end is plenty high so that there are no dropouts should something block the thread for a bit.  I'll choose codecs that are widely compatible (MP3 and AAC) with settings that prefer quality over latency.  I usually set a 20 second buffer up on the server, and distribute with HTTP progressive.

This gives me high quality audio that works on almost everything, from my 12 year old Palm Pilot to native `<audio>` tags in modern web browsers.  No app is needed... just a modern browser.  But, users with apps can use the streams because they are so compatible.  The latency is low enough that social media comments can be reacted to by the person hosting the show with minimal delay.  (The time it takes a human to read and respond to the comment is usually longer than the buffer sizes along the way.)  Having a 20s buffer enables mobile users to listen without constant glitches.  (As you rotate your phone around, it periodically loses its connection.  You don't notice due to buffers in everything, but you would definitely notice if you needed data every 50ms.)  Mobile networks are notoriously high latency networks anyway.  (Ping your media server from your phone.  If it returns in under 250ms, you're having a good day.)  In Chicago, the Blue Line subway has cell stations at every stop, but no coverage in between them.  The stops are fairly close together, and you can sort of get a signal a little ways down the track, but not a good one.  I wanted to be able to listen to internet radio on the subway, and a 20s buffer enabled that, without dropping out, even though I would completely lose cell connection for several seconds, repeatedly.  Your users might have similar use cases just walking down the street.

#### "Real-Time" Communication

To support what you want to do, you're going to need to lower all buffers you can down to almost nothing.  This means that you will have to accept low audio quality, with streams that drop out for short bursts of time.  You're also going to need to pick a codec designed for this (such as Opus), with appropriate settings for low latency (which again, reduce audio quality).  Technically speaking you could use HTTP progressive to distribute the media, but the players that use it don't assume a low-latency mode of operation, so that distribution method is out.

WebRTC is the most compatible method for web-based low latency audio/video, but has far less support than a normal HTTP stream.  Furthermore, WebRTC in general was developed for peer-to-peer connectivity between a handful of users for video chatting.  (Think Google Hangout or Skype.)  It supports audio-only and even data channels, but it wasn't built for one-to-many communications.  Because of that, there are only a couple servers in existence that actually support this method of distribution.  (I've never used them so I cannot provide a specific recommendation.)

A lot of folks use RTMP, but that doesn't work easily in browsers.  You have to use the MediaSourceExtensions.  It also doesn't reduce latency any more than HTTP Progressive does.  (I should note that in many implementations, RTMP has significantly lower latency than HTTP Progressive.  This has little to do with the protocol, and more to do with default configurations.)

> allows webcasts to work on ALL BROWSERS AND ALL DEVICES

There is no such thing as something that works on **all browsers** and **all devices**.  You need to figure out what browsers and devices you intend to support.  True universal support is an anti-goal.  Find a balance between supporting what your customer base uses, and your other goals.

> However, we've been told by other experts in the field that 1. Flash Player is outdated and doesn't work with all devices

This is very true.  There is better browser support for HTML5 methods than there is Flash.

> 2. HLS transcoding protocols may give us much latency issues with apple products.

HLS is not a transcoding protocol... HLS is a distribution protocol.  HLS will give you very high latency, with anything that uses it.  The concept behind HLS is that you chunk your media into large pieces (basically adding another large buffer to the chain) and then upload it to your server where it can be downloaded.  This will add another 10-30s, depending on your chunking configuration.  The benefit of HLS is that you don't need any special server to support it.  Any static web server will do, allowing you to use common HTTP CDNs.

> What dev path is best to eliminate all audio latency?

Again, this is physically impossible.  Even if I were to shout across my living room, there is latency, and that's without computers or a world-wide packet-switched network involved.

> Would a plug-in to a native app be best to eliminate audio latency?

Yes, if you throw out the goal of being supported on many devices, then a native app allows you to tune all sorts of parameters to *reduce* (not eliminate).  However, you still have the giant tradeoffs with quality of the audio and reliability of the stream.  In the end, it's extremely unlikely you would reduce latency beyond what a normal WebRTC stack will get you.

An Experiment:  Pick up your cell phone and call someone.  Get them to put you on speakerphone.  Shout something into the phone and wait for you to hear the feedback come back to you.  Telephony is *extremely* optimized for low latency, low bandwidth, and mobile devices, and has its own dedicated infrastructure...  yet round trip audio delays of 500ms are fairly normal.

## A Proposal

- Determine how many people will be listening to each stream.  (The answer can't be "1 to ∞".  This needs to be known, roughly.)  If the answer is <8, implement WebRTC and be done with it.  Very simple, well supported, and requires little infrastructure as most of your users will connect to each other peer-to-peer.
- If you need more listeners than that, I suggest streaming with HTTP progressive, with a tuned configuration on Icecast or compatible.  (I have a CDN product that fits the bill.  E-mail me at brad@audiopump.co for more information.)  Set your server buffer to the *highest* you're willing to accept.  If that's 2s, then so be it.  The higher you go, the more reliable your streams will be.  I would pick 2s as the minimum, as that's what it takes to fill up client buffers for decoding anyway.  If you send data to them quickly, they start playback quickly.  Also remember that as your listeners increase, you don't want them all connected to a single server.  There are additional delays in relaying that data as you scale horizontally.
- Determine what devices and browsers you want to support.  (The answer can't be "all", but it can be "as many as reasonably possible".)  This will answer the question of what codecs you want to support.

One final note... do all of your encoding up-front if at all possible.  Don't transcode anything.  Transcoding will add to your latency problem, but more importantly, will reduce your audio quality significantly.

I hope this is helpful to your project.